# SSRS SQL Server Authentications

Tags: sql-server, authentication, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

I'm having an issue with an SSRS report using **SQL Server Authentication**.

I'm creating the report in VS2017 (SSDT), latest update 05/11/2018.

Creating a pretty basic report with 2 data sources.  The data sources appear to be valid and passes test.
Test Connection:
[image: Connection Successful]

When I attempt to preview the report SSRS throws the obtuse error

> An error occurred during local report processing

[image: Preview results w/SQL Server Authentication]

By changing the credentials from **SQL Server Authentication** to **Windows Authentication** I can preview the report just fine:
[image: Preview results w/Windows Authentication]

There are no reported login failures in the logs of the target SQL server so it would appear that the report is failing prior to the login.

I'm a little befuddled and appreciate any insights the community could provide.

Comment: I'm confused by your tags. Visual Studio 2017 can't deploy to SSRS 2008. If you're using SQL Server 2008, you need to use BIDS (Business Information Development Studios), which is an extension of VS 2008. On a different note, the output window should have more details on the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your data set to shared data set. I also faced the same problem when i upgraded my ssdt.